# youtube-dl CommandNotFoundException

Tags: youtube-dl

As I'm trying to get some high quality audio files of some ambient background in order to use in my music, the first I read was to use youtube-dl to download and ffmpeg to convert to a format FL Studio can actually import (damn you, aac and m4a).

Now, following the instructions I simply downloaded youtube-dl for Windows and then tried to call it via cmd/powershell (I tried both). All it says is this:

> Die Benennung "youtube-dl" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.

This roughly translates to:

> The name "youtube-dl" was not recognized as name of a cmdlet, a function, a script or executable file. Please check the spelling of the name and whether the path is correct and retry the process.

Here's the command I used:

```
youtube-dl -f bestaudio (video url) -o /Download/(filename).mp4
```

I did google for this error but I didn't find anything specific to youtube-dl. I added the .exe file to the `PATH` variable and tried the command `youtube-dl` as well as `youtube-dl.exe`, which both throws the same error. I have tried to install c++ redistributable 2010 with the installer telling me that I already have a newer version installed. I also tried installing the python interpreter despite the site actually mentioning that it's not needed for the windows exe.

This is highly frustrating, how can I get this program to run?

**EDIT:**

After trying to run the command as `.\youtube-dl.exe` I'm getting the following result (translation by myself):

> Error trying to execute program "youtube-dl.exe": Access deniedAt line:1 character:1
>   + .\youtube-dl.exe -f bestaudio (video link) -o /(filen...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
>   At Line:1 Character:1
>   + .\youtube-dl.exe -f bestaudio (video link) -o /(filen...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

Comment: Where did you download youtube-dl from?

Comment: Did your restart your `cmd` shell when you changed the `PATH`?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, I did. But being in the folder location already starting the command with youtube-dl.exe, shouldn't the `PATH` variable be irrelevant anyway?

Comment: @DavidPostill This is the site I downloaded it from: https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I had the exe file itself added to the `PATH`, but even after changing that to the folder the exe resides in I get the same error. Also, as I mentioned I already tried navigating to the folder in the cmd and then running the exe, which should work.

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher Oh, gotcha!! 10-4, roger that!!! Must have been a reading oversight on my part. Maybe try another version of the app or that app from another Windows PC. Very odd, I don't have the app to test here though.

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher Works for me on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit. Perhaps your download if youtube-dl is corrupted ?

Comment: Another quick idea.... go to command prompt and change to the directory. When in the directory do a `dir` and confirm you see the exe in there. If so then in that same path `you` and press tab and confirm it's resolving to the exe in case there's another file with that same name but a different extension since it's the `.exe`—perhaps it's trying to use another file in that path since you don't specify the extension. Probably won't help but simply enough to try I suppose.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/RfKxx0h.png

Comment: Tried it on my notebook, same result. Both machines run on Win10 x64. Even if I specify the extension, same result. There also is no other file with that same name.

Comment: I have now tried `.\youtube-dl.exe` which did cause a different exception. I will edit my answer as the text is probably too long for a comment

Comment: Okay, so try to create a folder on the root of the "C" drive like `C:\youtube-dl` and then drop all the app files in there and then run from that directory and see what happens. Just do the CD to it or whatever to see if that resolves. It seems the context of the execution of that command from within the folder it resides now is denied. What is the full path where the youtube-dl executable resides now on your PC?

Comment: The full path is `E:\Media\YoutubeConvert\youtube-dl.exe` on my tower and `D:\Downloads\youtube-dl.exe` on my notebook. I may try your suggestion after work.

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher Did you ever figure out and get resolved?